# Merge two commands

Tags: php, imagemagick

For watermark:

```
exec("composite.exe -watermark 85% -gravity southeast a.jpg -depth 8 a.jpg")
```

For thumbnail:

```
exec('convert.exe a.jpg -resize 150x150  thumba.jpg');
```

How can I merge two commands to one command?

How can I increase speed watermark and create thumbnail?

Is this command very slow?

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Is the command slow or not? I don't know, you tell me.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define those commands to be "very slow"?

---

To "merge" two commands into single line use semicolon `;` or logical AND operator `&&`:

```
exec("composite.exe -watermark 85% -gravity southeast a.jpg -depth 8 a.jpg ; convert.exe a.jpg -resize 150x150  thumba.jpg");
```

Also the following command-line syntax is allowed:

```
convert a.jpg thumba.jpg -resize 150x150 -composite -watermark 85% -gravity southeast a.jpg -depth 8 a.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

That method looks interesting @RomaPerekhrest I had never thought of putting multiple commands in one exec()

This untested method should also work:

```
exec("composite.exe -watermark 85% -gravity southeast a.jpg -depth 8 miff:- | convert.exe - -resize 150x150 thumba.jpg");
```

I do not know why the OP has the .exe extensions but if they want to use them I will not argue.